# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

I am using springboot 1.4 with weblogic  12.2.1.4 server .when i am deploying my application onto WL server their is a an  error like

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener**

can anyone help on this .

Comment: Well you are missing a dependency and thus the class not found.

Comment: I am having deppendenices in pom.xml like below

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

and also 
<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
     </dependency>

Comment: Nice that you have dependencies but you don't have the dependency that has the needed class.

Comment: Thanks Denium,  what else are required for that can you please suggest me .

Comment: The Spring Boot Legacy project (I assume you aren't just blindly copying from StackOverflow and have some sense of what you are doing).

Comment: Hi Deinum ,
i am having below legacy  dependency in my pom.xml.

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>

Do i need to make the higher version to avoid that Exception  kindly  suggest me.

Comment: Use the version that is compatible with Spring Boot version you are using. Also do you really need it when using WebLogic 12?

Answer (score 0):

This was separated into a legacy project, so you just have to add the following dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```